# Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php, file-get-contents, remote-debugging

This is my code bellow:

```
$ip_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=119.82.67.243"));
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($ip_data);
die;
```

When I run this 2 different on 1 system its ok but on second system its giving error

> Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known

I have already checked `allow_url_fopen=On` is on both system so please suggest some other soln...thanks

Comment: Try restarting your webserver.
(Possible explanation: Your router may have reconnected to the internet, obtaining new DNS-adresses, and PHP still uses old DNS-adresses.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- try to flush your DNS cache and try again :) if it doesn't help:
- try to do this that way: fopen('your url','r')... but i think this won't change anything

If there is a problem with dns on second environment you can do this:

```
<?php
echo gethostbyname("ONLY_ HOST_HERE_WITHOUT_HTTP_PROTOCOL"); // debug
var_export (dns_get_record ( "ONLY_HOST_HERE_WITHOUT_HTTP_PROTOCOL") ); ?>
```

and you can change your dns servers:

```
$dns=array("194.204.159.1","194.204.152.34","8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4"); // or you can pass DNS from your first machine :)
var_export (dns_get_record ( "ONLY_ HOST_HERE_WITHOUT_HTTP_PROTOCOL" ,  DNS_ALL , $dns ));
```

Comment: I am running it on my localhost

Comment: What this returns: 

$dns=array("194.204.159.1","194.204.152.34","8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4"); var_export (dns_get_record ( "geoplugin.net" ,  DNS_ALL , $dns )); ??